# Ajax post to CodeIgniter controller not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to post some data to CodeIgniter controller, but it only shows empty array. I'm also using DataTables. I'm not sure that I'm sending the data the right way. This is my code:

JS

```
$("#prw").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = window.location.origin + "/nsl/preview";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").serialize()
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log("Response", data);
    });
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
function preview() {
    $post = $this->input->post();
    return $post;
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="offers" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach($data as $d): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="toggle" value="<?=$d->oid?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rb" name="myText[]" class="toggle"></td>
            <td><?=$d->fullname?></td>
            <td><?=$d->published?></td>
            <td><?=$d->expires?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" id="prw" class="btn btn-info" value="Preview">
```

Please I appreciate any help.

Comment: Normally ajax calls should work fine with proper MVC paths. Be sure to point to the right controller/method. Then try debugging the ajax first with .beforeSend() and see if your "data" looks fine. Next - simplify your controller method to return your $_POST[] - this will give you an end to end certainty that everything works as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain things to check :-

1. Inside the ajax call, mention `type : 'post'`
2. On click function, try

   alert( $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").serialize() );

   and check whether you are getting the values as expected?
3. Open Firebug, Click on Console, execute the click button, see what all values are present under POST tab of the URL inside the console.
4. Inside the controller

   $post = $this->input->post('myCheckboxes');
   print_r($post);